# Don't want to Update Entity in EF 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have a method that is reading a data entity from the database, converting it to a view model. Then in the method, there is a another table that gets updated. As a result, the first entity change was committed back to the database.

How can I get around this? Is it the way I am attaching the OrderHeader entity to the view model? Note viewMode.OrderHeader is of type OrderHeader. Is there a way to denote that I am working with just a copy of the data so the subsequent commit won't save these changes? Do I need to detach this entity from the context?

```
public OrderHeaderViewModel ConvertClassToViewModel(OrderHeader entity)
            {
                OrderHeaderViewModel viewModel = new OrderHeaderViewModel();
                viewModel.OrderHeader = entity;
                viewModel.OrderHeader.CustomerRequestedDateTime =
                    ManageTimeDetailsAppServ.ConvertFromUTCDateTime(viewModel.OrderHeader.CustomerRequestedDateTime).Value; <------ THIS CHANGE IS BEING COMMITTED TO THE DB.
                return viewModel;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding the [.AsNoTracking()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to the repository search.

```
var orderHdr = _orderHeaderRepository.SearchFor(predicate).AsNoTracking().Single();
```